# How to quality check this data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df1 with 820 rows:

```
ID        College   Score    Score3
EI01      0         1        2
EI01      0         1        6
EI08,EI07 1         4        4
EI08,EI07 1         4        8
EI02      0         0        9
EI05      1         2        2
EI06      1         10       12
```

I have a df2 with 713 rows:

```
ID          Points
EI01        20
EI08,EI07   12
EI02        30
EI04        10
```

I have tried merging these two df by "ID" with all=FALSE but my new merged df is 864 rows, when I would only like it to maximally be 820 rows given the # in df1. I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Additionally, I would like to make a df3 that includes all of the IDs in df1 that are not present in df2.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: how? They are 800 rows. I tried to give examples of the data above

Comment: Just the same example as you showed above in a reproducible format that can be copied into R.

Comment: Does this work? `dplyr::left_join(df1,df2)`?

Comment: Please show the exact code that you have tried. Also, if you want to keep all the ID's of `df1` you should use `all.x = TRUE` instead of `all = FALSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join data and have an automatic QC check, you could consider using the `tidylog` package, which replaces many `dplyr` functions with more verbose ones.

Here's an example of `tidylog::left_join()` with your sample data:

```
> left_join(df1,df2)
Joining, by = "ID"
left_join: added one column (Points)
           > rows only in x   2
           > rows only in y  (1)
           > matched rows     5
           >                 ===
           > rows total       7
          ID College Score Score3 Points
1:      EI01       0     1      2     20
2:      EI01       0     1      6     20
3: EI08,EI07       1     4      4     12
4: EI08,EI07       1     4      8     12
5:      EI02       0     0      9     30
6:      EI05       1     2      2     NA
7:      EI06       1    10     12     NA
```

To find IDs that are in `df1` and not in `df2` you can use:

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(!ID %in% df2$ID) %>% 
  pull(ID)


[1] "EI05" "EI06"
```

Comment: Is there a way to also get an output of all the ID's from df1 that are not in df2

Comment: @Evan, yes, I updated the answer.